# Safe Rails HTML translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Following the rails guides [as per the posting title](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-safe-html-translations), the YAML local files were set in a Rails 6.1.3 application as follows:

```
authorisation_request: Payment to be authorised; </br>Final <b>exact charge</b> </br>will reflect <b>delivered goods</b>.
authorisation_request_html: Payment to be authorised; </br>Final <b>exact charge</b> </br>will reflect <b>delivered goods</b>.
```

In the view, three experiments were conducted:

```
  <i><%= t('cart.authorisation_request').capitalize %></i>
  <i><%= raw t('cart.authorisation_request_html').capitalize %></i>
  <i><%= t('cart.authorisation_request_html').capitalize %></i>
```

The first one rendered the tags as expected straight text, the middle one rendered as expected both the break and bold tags.

But the last one was rendered identical to the first.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

When a translation key has the `_html` suffix, you can call it as if it did not, and it will automatically treat the key as HTML safe.

The way you are displaying the translation key is not as intended, instead of doing:

```
<%= t('cart.authorisation_request_html').capitalize %>
```

You should be doing:

```
<%= t('cart.authorisation_request').capitalize %>
```

Then the I18n system will see that there is an `_html`-suffixed variant, and mark that as HTML safe to display as-is. The way you are doing it now, the system would be looking for a key named `authorization_request_html_html` (double suffixed) and not find it.

More info on Safe HTML Translations: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-safe-html-translations

As a side-note, you should probably be capitalizing your source translated text, and not modifying it afterwards with the `.capitalize` helper. If that text were translated to another language, the capitalization could probably look pretty strange in some languages.

Comment: As the question describes, i did, as suggested `<%= t('cart.authorisation_request').capitalize %>` (first test) => it is not rendered HTML safe.  If I remove the `authorisation_request` entry, then the dreaded `translation missing: it.cart.authorisation_request` gets generated...

Comment: You need to remove the `authorization_request` key. Because it has HTML in it, but is not marked as HTML safe. Then, when you call `t('cart.authorization_request')`, it will not find that key, then look for the alternate with the `_html` suffix and load it as HTML safe.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did: "If I remove the `authorisation_request` entry," ... Only `authorisation_request_html` key remains & the `t('cart.authorisation_request')` call returns the 'translation missing message - only the second experiment above renders as expected.  So there has to be something else at play here...